# Distributed Tensorflow: TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'dtype'

Tags: tensorflow, distributed

When running distributed tensorflow following the [inception distributed training tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception), I encountered the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/AIJ/tf_models/models/inception/bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_distributed_train.runfiles/inception/inception/imagenet_distributed_train.py", line 65, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/home/AIJ/tensorflow/_python_build/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 44, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "/home/AIJ/tf_models/models/inception/bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_distributed_train.runfiles/inception/inception/imagenet_distributed_train.py", line 61, in main
    inception_distributed_train.train(server.target, dataset, cluster_spec)
  File "/home/AIJ/tf_models/models/inception/bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_distributed_train.runfiles/inception/inception/inception_distributed_train.py", line 120, in train
    global_step = slim.variables.global_step()
  File "/home/AIJ/tf_models/models/inception/bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_distributed_train.runfiles/inception/inception/slim/scopes.py", line 155, in func_with_args
    return func(*args, **current_args)
  File "/home/AIJ/tf_models/models/inception/bazel-bin/inception/imagenet_distributed_train.runfiles/inception/inception/slim/variables.py", line 244, in global_step
    trainable=False, collections=collections)
  File "/home/AIJ/tensorflow/_python_build/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 988, in get_variable
    custom_getter=custom_getter)
  File "/home/AIJ/tensorflow/_python_build/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 890, in get_variable
    custom_getter=custom_getter)
  File "/home/AIJ/tensorflow/_python_build/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 348, in get_variable
    validate_shape=validate_shape)
  File "/home/AIJ/tensorflow/_python_build/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 333, in _true_getter
    caching_device=caching_device, validate_shape=validate_shape)
  File "/home/AIJ/tensorflow/_python_build/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 684, in _get_single_variable
    validate_shape=validate_shape)
  File "/home/AIJ/tensorflow/_python_build/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 226, in __init__
    expected_shape=expected_shape)
  File "/home/AIJ/tensorflow/_python_build/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 303, in _init_from_args
    initial_value(), name="initial_value", dtype=dtype)
  File "/home/AIJ/tensorflow/_python_build/tensorflow/python/ops/variable_scope.py", line 673, in <lambda>
    shape.as_list(), dtype=dtype, partition_info=partition_info)
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'dtype'
```

I think the problem is due to api mismatch somewhere in `slim`. The tensorflow version I used is `v1.0.0-alpha`. Could anyone help me on this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. It may be due to api mismatch. The solution is to change line 243 in [inception/slim/variables.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/slim/variables.py) to `initializer=tf.zeros_initializer()`.

Please tell me if there is anything wrong.

Comment: Yep, just have to add parentheses. A result of API standardization efforts.